# XML not displaying using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

When the XML file is loaded no data shows. It seems to not use the XSL file, I just get a blank screen. Please could someone have a look and see why it may be doing this. Thanks in advance.

Heres my code:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="computers.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE computers SYSTEM "computers.dtd">
<computers>
    <computer>
    <cpu ghz="3.5" unlocked="Yes">Intel i7 3770k</cpu>
    <motherboard>MSI M-Power</motherboard>
    <ram>8</ram>
    <storage>
        <hdd>1000</hdd>
        <ssd>128</ssd>
    </storage>
    <gpu group="ATI">7950</gpu>
    <psu>750</psu>
</computer>
<computer>
    <cpu ghz="3.5" unlocked="Yes">Intel i5 3570k</cpu>
    <motherboard>ASRock Extreme 4</motherboard>
    <ram>8</ram>
    <storage>
        <hdd>1000</hdd>
    </storage>
    <gpu group="ATI">7870</gpu>
    <psu>600</psu>
</computer>
<computer>
    <cpu ghz="3.5" unlocked="No">Intel i5 3550</cpu>
    <motherboard>ASRock Extreme 3</motherboard>
    <ram>8</ram>
    <storage>
        <hdd>500</hdd>
    </storage>
    <gpu group="GeForce">9600GT</gpu>
    <psu>500</psu>
</computer>
 </computers>
```

DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT computer (cpu,motherboard,ram,storage,gpu,psu) >
<!ELEMENT cpu (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT motherboard (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ram (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT storage(hdd,ssd*)>
<!ELEMENT hdd (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ssd (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT gpu (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT psu (#PCDATA)>

<!ATLIST cpu
ghz CDATA #REQUIRED
unlocked (Yes|No) "No">
<!ATLIST gpu
group (ATI|GeForce) "ATI">
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
    <title>HELLO WORLD</title>
</head>
<body>
    <xsl:for-each select="computers/computer">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="cpu"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="cpu/@ghz"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="cpu/@unlocked"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="motherboard"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ram"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:for-each select="storage"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="hdd"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ssd"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="gpu"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="psu"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the XSLT stylesheet being malformed (not well-formed XML) document, there don't seem to be other problems.

**1. Replace on line 33**:

```
                <xsl:for-each select="storage"/>
```

**with**

```
                <xsl:for-each select="storage">
```

**2. Remove from the source XML document the `<!DOCTYPE computers SYSTEM "computers.dtd">` -- it isn't used by the XSLT transformation and is unnecessary. An XSLT transformation only uses from a DTD data about ID attributes -- and there are none in the provided DTD**.

After this replacement and removal, the transformation runs without problem and when applied on the provided XML document:

```
<computers>
    <computer>
        <cpu ghz="3.5" unlocked="Yes">Intel i7 3770k</cpu>
        <motherboard>MSI M-Power</motherboard>
        <ram>8</ram>
        <storage>
            <hdd>1000</hdd>
            <ssd>128</ssd>
        </storage>
        <gpu group="ATI">7950</gpu>
        <psu>750</psu>
    </computer>
    <computer>
        <cpu ghz="3.5" unlocked="Yes">Intel i5 3570k</cpu>
        <motherboard>ASRock Extreme 4</motherboard>
        <ram>8</ram>
        <storage>
            <hdd>1000</hdd>
        </storage>
        <gpu group="ATI">7870</gpu>
        <psu>600</psu>
    </computer>
    <computer>
        <cpu ghz="3.5" unlocked="No">Intel i5 3550</cpu>
        <motherboard>ASRock Extreme 3</motherboard>
        <ram>8</ram>
        <storage>
            <hdd>500</hdd>
        </storage>
        <gpu group="GeForce">9600GT</gpu>
        <psu>500</psu>
    </computer>
</computers>
```

**the following (which I guess is the wanted) result is produced**:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

      <title>HELLO WORLD</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>Intel i7 3770k</td>
            <td>3.5</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>MSI M-Power</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>8</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>1000128</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>7950</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>750</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>Intel i5 3570k</td>
            <td>3.5</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>ASRock Extreme 4</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>8</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>1000</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>7870</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>600</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>Intel i5 3550</td>
            <td>3.5</td>
            <td>No</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>ASRock Extreme 3</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>8</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>500</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>9600GT</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>500</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**All four browsers: IE, FF, Safari and Opera correctly process computers.xml and produce the wanted display**.

I don't get anything with Chrome -- this browser is known to have issues when processing local files.

Comment: I didn't even check it using different browsers (duh). Tried it with firefox and it was fine so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your XSLT is not well-formed and your XSLT processor (which I suspect is a browser) is probably just refusing to process it. You should remove the slash from this `for-each`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="storage"/>
```

Once you do that, I believe that the XSLT will work successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that didn't fix it. Can you see any other issues with the markup?